# Why did I get Queue[Nothing] instead of Queue[Book] from this code?

Tags: scala, type-inference

Here is an example from the stairway book (with some modifications):

```
object Example {
  class Queue[+T] private (
                          private[this] var leading: List[T],
                          private [this] var trailing: List[T]
                            ) {
    private def mirror: Unit = {
      if(leading.isEmpty) {
        while(!trailing.isEmpty) {
          leading = trailing.head :: leading
          trailing = trailing.tail
        }
      }
    }

    def this() = this(Nil, Nil)

    def head: T = {
      mirror
      leading.head
    }

    def tail: Queue[T] = {
      mirror
      new Queue(leading.tail, trailing)
    }

    def enqueue[U >: T](x: U) = new Queue[U](leading, x :: trailing)

    def enqueue[U >: T](xs: U*) = new Queue[U](leading, xs.reverse.toList ::: trailing)

    def size = leading.size + trailing.size
  }

  object Queue {
    def apply[T, U <: T](xs: U*): Queue[T] = new Queue(xs.toList, Nil)
    def apply[T]: Queue[T] = new Queue[T](Nil, Nil)
  }

  class Publication
  class Book extends Publication
  class Novel extends Book
  class Journal extends Publication
  class Magazine extends Publication

}

object Test {

  import Example._
  {
    val q = new Queue[Int]()
    val q1 = q.enqueue[Int](1, 2, 3)
    q1.head // 1
    val p = Queue(new Book, new Book, new Book) // Queue[Nothing] ?
  }
}
```

I get a `p` of the type `Queue[Nothing]` from this line:

```
    val p = Queue(new Book, new Book, new Book) // Queue[Nothing] ?
```

I was expecting a `Queue[Book]`. How did the compiler arrive at that conclusion and how can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type parameters are confusing the type inference, I think because of second constructor parameter `Nil`. Use only one type parameter `T`:

```
  object Queue {
    //    def apply[T, U <: T](xs: U*): Queue[T] = new Queue(xs.toList, Nil)
    def apply[T](xs: T*): Queue[T] = new Queue(xs.toList, Nil)

    def apply[T]: Queue[T] = new Queue[T](Nil, Nil)
  }
```

This is how it works now:

```
val b1 = new Book
val b2 = new Magazine
val b3 = new Journal
val p = Queue(b1, b2, b3)  // Example.Queue[Example.Publication]
```

This correctly inferred the type as `Publication`.